# Edit log out link

Tags: navigation

I have a Log out link in a menu which is pointed to user/logout. I'm trying to edit the name "Log out" to something else like "Sign out". How can I do that?

Comment: Go to admin/structure/menus/UserMenu
list the menu, you can see logout link, edit that and change the text to whatever you want.
Thanks

Comment: I tried that. It works for other links. But not for the log out link which points to user/logout

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive about what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to globally change "Log out" to "Sign out".

Comment: This worked :D..

Answer (score 2):

If you are going the route of changing "log out" to "sign out" globally, you can achieve that without adding a module. Look near the bottom of settings.php for the string overrides section. There are instructions there and examples.

Comment: I think it's just a matter of preference, but the OP seems to not be a coder so I gave the option with a gui :)